# Changing file path of js and css files in production build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I need some assistance or at least to be pointed in the right direction.  I am attempting to deploy a vuejs app using Vue CLI 3.  When I run the build command the files are built into the dist folder, which works fine.  There is also a js and css folder inside dist that contain the respective files.  In my index.html is created the paths as /css/app.css or /js/app.js.  I want the files to just be placed in the dist folder along with index.html and the paths to read simply app.css or app.js.  My goal is to remove the /css/.

I am assuming this is accomplished in the vue.config.js by configuring webpack.  I can’t seem to figure this out.  I understand the baseURL setting but I can figure this part out..any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's answered here
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1967

basically config should look like this

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
      .use('url-loader')
      .tap(options => Object.assign({}, options, {
        name: '[name].[ext]'
      }));
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[name].css',
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: this seems to work, the only issue is that it  is giving me /app.js,  I need to have app.js without the slash show up in the HTML.  I am deploying this as a portlet in websphere portal and this is the only way that it works correctly.

Comment: I added publicPath: ‘’ in the output object under configureWebpack and that solved the issue